# php redirect and log in

Tags: php, redirect, curl, post

I am relatively new to php but am attempting to redirect and log in to an external url from my app. I have credentials and attempting to POST them but all I can really achieve is "success". If I do redirect, either by laravel's ->redirect() or header(location: blah.php) I get the error that my credentials weren't sent. I have attempted to use cURL and Guzzle so far. Is there a working example of a redirect with login credentials passed?

attempt 1:

```
$client = new Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));

        $url = "url.php";
        $data = array('email' => 'user@email.com', "pass" => 'pass' );
        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $res = $client->post($url, [ 'body' => $data_string ]);
        $code = $res->getStatusCode();

        if($code == '200'){
            $this->redirect($url);

           // return redirect()->away($url);
        } else {
            return redirect('/register')
    }
```

attempt 2:

```
$POSTFIELDS = json_encode($data);
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt"; 
$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'w');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = @curl_exec ($ch);

if($result) {
    header("Location: url.php");
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

expected behavior, user saves data in current app, is added to db on registration then these credentials passed to legacy app for sign in, where they see that page as though they logged in there.

Comment: So us what you have tried and what is output and what is your expected output??

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI, please see edits

Comment: Well, there are two different sessions here. One between the user and your server, and one between your server and your legacy app. You need to set the session cookie from the legacy app to your user session.

Comment: @DaanMeijer can you eli5/ psuedo code that at all?

Comment: I've tried to provide helpful pseudo-code in my answer. Hope it's clear :)

Comment: @DaanMeijer I'm having issues getting these two apps to talk to each other in this way... right now I have them both locally. In the app passing the cookie, I did a $response->withCookie(cookie('test', 'test', 45000));
 I attempted in the second app to get this cookie, but there is nothing present for it to retrieve. Am I going about this in the wrong way or is just not possible

Comment: You need to rethink what software is making which request. The way I understand is that your PHP script makes a request (a call to log your visitor in, in a legacy app). This results in a session, represented by a cookie. You need to somehow relay this session (cookie) to the user's browser.

Comment: @DaanMeijer I'd really just like to push the user to the legacy app with login data from current app. More and more this use case isn't looking like its going to work.

Comment: I've elaborated my answer, adding another solution route. Hope this one is workable for you :)

Comment: thank you @DaanMeijer i do believe i'll go that route as path of least resistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to carry the session. Something like:

```
$cookies = curl_get_cookies($curl_handle);
$session_cookie = $cookies['PHPSESSID'];
session_set('PHPSESSID', $session_cookie);
```

Alternatively, you could generate an auto-posting HTML form. Something like:

```
<form id="auto-login" method="POST" action="<?PHP echo htmlentitites($url); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?PHP echo htmlentities('user@email.com'); ?>" />        
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="<?PHP echo htmlentities('pass'); ?>" />
</form>

<script>
$('#auto-login').submit();
</script>
```